# Visual studio - error with dll.

Tags: visual-studio, exception, dll, compiler-errors

I keep getting this issue time and again. I change something in the code, and build the VS project and I get a exception with some dll in the bin folder. 
Unable to copy so and so file to the bin/folder... access is denied.

I can delete the entire bin folder and re build it.. but this one file thats causing the issue cannot be delete, cannot be renamed... in such situations, what can I do? any help is great appreciated.

Comment: One of your dlls or some third party?. Sopund of it some process is still using it. Design time? Some process kicked off by your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use unlocker: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/
it will unlock the file and let you delete it and also tell you which process is locking it so that you can figure out a way to avoid it